# Similar matrices and rref

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a hunch that all conjugate/similar matrices have the same [reduced row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). Am I right?

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not true.

For instance, matrices

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0   &   1  \\
0   &   0
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
B = \frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1   &   -1  \\
1   &   -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

are similar matrices, the change of basis matrix being

$$
S=
\begin{pmatrix}
1   &   1   \\
1   &   -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

That is, $B = S^{-1}AS$, as you can easily verify.

$A$ is already in reduced row echelon form and the reduced row echelon form for $B$ is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1   & -1  \\
0   &  0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Geometrical interpretation.** Your guess amounts to say, for instance, that a straight line should have the same equations in no matter which basis. Indeed, $A$ is the matrix of the system of linear equations $y = 0$ (the $x$-axis, in the standard basis) and $B$ is the matrix of the system of linear equations $\overline{x} - \overline{y} = 0$, which is the same straight line, but with coordinates in the basis $(1,1),(1, -1)$.